# Multiple HTTP Patch method is not working in mule

Tags: mule

I have an HTTPS outbound that call twice in the project. It create entries in the endpoint server database.

```
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="PATCH" address="https://${ICIMS_USER_NAME}:${ICIMS_PASSWORD}@#[person_url.replaceAll(&quot;https://&quot;,&quot;&quot;)]?fields=bgcresults"  doc:name="Patch Test"/>
```

But eventhough the request is the same, it does not create entry for second call. Any cache or something I need to remove ?

I do not see any entry created in listening application only for second call. First call it create fine.

It is not the issue with listening server.

Comment: Are you sure this is executed twice on Mule? Do you see Mule doing the outbound dispatch twice in the logs?

Comment: Yes I do. Still I do not know why it is failing.. Probably it is destination server issue. Still it is not a concurrent request!!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add Mule log lines that show the doubled HTTP dispatches?